# Android: ImageLoader not working for single Image? NullPointerException but nothing is Null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have this code to display Image from the web and save it as a cache, but all I got always a NullPointer.

```
ImageView projectImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.project_image);
setViewImage(projectImage, project.bigImageUrl);

public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
        v.setTag(value);
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(activity);
        System.out.println(v);
        loader.displayImage(value, activity, v);
    }
```

here's the stakcktrace:

```
05-20 11:28:35.415: INFO/System.out(645): http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/small/1264073994.jpg
05-20 11:28:35.425: INFO/System.out(645): spendino.de.ProjectDetail@43c0ee08
05-20 11:28:35.435: INFO/System.out(645): android.widget.ImageView@43be1550
05-20 11:28:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(645): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 11:28:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(645):  at spendino.de.ProjectDetail.setViewImage(ProjectDetail.java:81)
05-20 11:28:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(645):     at spendino.de.ProjectDetail.onCreate(ProjectDetail.java:48)
```

Here's the ImageLoader class:

```
public class ImageLoaderCache {

    Context context;
    //the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    /** The cache. */
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    /** The cache dir. */
    private File cacheDir;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new image loader.
     *
     * @param context the context
     */
    public ImageLoaderCache(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"spendino.de");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }
    //This is used for a stub when the user can not see the actual image..
    //this images will be seen
    final int stub_id =R.drawable.list_icon;


    /**
     * Display image.
     *
     * @param url the url
     * @param activity the activity
     * @param imageView the image view
     */
    public void displayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        if(cache.containsKey(url))
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    /**
     * Queue photo.
     *
     * @param url the url
     * @param activity the activity
     * @param imageView the image view
     */
    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the bitmap.
     *
     * @param url the url
     * @return the bitmap
     */
    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {

            String filename = String.valueOf(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
            // from web
            try
            {
                if(!f.exists())
                {
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                    os.close();
                    bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                    return bitmap;
                }
                else
                {               
                    Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                    return bitmap;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                BitmapDrawable mDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_icon);
                return mDrawable.getBitmap();
            }

    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    /**
     * Decode file.
     *
     * @param f the f
     * @return the bitmap
     */
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale++;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    /**
     * The Class PhotoToLoad.
     */
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {

        /** The url. */
        public String url;

        /** The image view. */
        public ImageView imageView;

        /**
         * Instantiates a new photo to load.
         *
         * @param u the u
         * @param i the i
         */
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    /** The photos queue. */
    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    /**
     * Stop thread.
     */
    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    /**
     * The Class PhotosQueue.
     */
    class PhotosQueue
    {

        /** The photos to load. */
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        /**
         * Clean.
         *
         * @param image the image
         */
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The Class PhotosLoader.
     */
    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
         */
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        if(((String)photoToLoad.imageView.getTag()).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }


                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    /** The photo loader thread. */
    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    /**
     * The Class BitmapDisplayer.
     */
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {

        /** The bitmap. */
        Bitmap bitmap;

        /** The image view. */
        ImageView imageView;

        /**
         * Instantiates a new bitmap displayer.
         *
         * @param b the b
         * @param i the i
         */
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
         */
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
              imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clear cache.
     */
    public void clearCache() {
        //clear memory cache
        cache.clear();

        //clear SD cache
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

     public static void copyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
            final int buffer_size=1024;
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
                for(;;)
                {
                  int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                  if(count==-1)
                      break;
                  os.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }


}
```

Can anybody give me a solution to my problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Tell us which is the 81st line of code in your activity (ProjectDetails.java)?

Comment: loader is null again check http://esilo.pl/LooserSample.zip

Comment: here's line 81:  loader.displayImage(value, activity, v); thank you

Comment: Hi Selvin, I'm checking out..awesome thx! by the way, how to show the characters like äöüß ? Is the problem with my encoding on the JSON file maybe?

Comment: yes, your server should return text as utf-8

Answer (score 0):

```
private static InputStream fetch(String urlString)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    conn = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    return  conn.getInputStream();
}
Resources res;
// ***********New Function For Fatching
public static Drawable LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
    Drawable drawable = null; Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        if (fetch(URL) != null) {
            try {
                InputStream obj = (InputStream)fetch(URL);
                 bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(obj,null,options);
                obj.close();
                conn.disconnect();
            } catch(OutOfMemoryError e){}
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
                 drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
                return drawable;
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    DefaultDisplay.mContext.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.profileplaceholder);
         drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            return drawable;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("GUIMethodClasas", "fetchDrawable failed", e);
        return null;

    }

}
```

i am using this LoadImage function for fetching image form url it is working fine.Just pass the url and bitmapoption value like 1,2,3,4,5 according to bitmap quality.
I hope you got your answer.